# InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 88064 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 38912 [[{{node Reshape_17}}]]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a sequence to sequence model with attention mechanism for building a chat-bot, but i stuck with below error can anyone help where i did wrong 
Below is the code for Attention mechanism(Bhaidu attention) inspired from tensor flow examples

```
#Bahdanu attention 
#parameters to pass this attention 
'''
1.Encoder state's i.e.., state_c, state_h
2.encoder_outputs 
3.decoder_embedding which is in decoder part 
4.you will get a context vector named "input_to_decoder" pass this as input to decoder lstm layer 
'''
def B_Attention_layer(state_h,state_c,encoder_outputs,decoder_embedding):

  d0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_1')
  d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_2')
  d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_3')
  hidden_with_time_axis_1 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(state_h, 1)
  #hidden_with_time_axis_1 = state_h
  hidden_with_time_axis_2 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(state_c, 1)
  #hidden_with_time_axis_2 = state_c
  #hidden_states = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([state_h,state_c],axis=-1)
  #all_states = tf.keras.layers.concatenate()
  score = d0(tf.keras.activations.tanh(encoder_outputs) + d1(hidden_with_time_axis_1) +  d2(hidden_with_time_axis_2))
  attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(score, axis=1)
  #attention = Dense(38)(attention_weights)
  context_vector = attention_weights * encoder_outputs
  context_vector = tf.keras.backend.sum(context_vector, axis=1)
  context_vector = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(context_vector, 1)
  context_vector = tf.keras.backend.reshape(context_vector,[-1,38,1024])
  input_to_decoder = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([context_vector,decoder_embedding])

  return input_to_decoder
```

Below is Encoder-decoder Model i,e.,,, seq-seq model

```
#Encoder inputs 
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(38,),name='encoder_input_layer')
encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 1024, mask_zero=True,name='encoder_embedding_layer')(encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs , state_h , state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024, return_state=True,return_sequences=True)(encoder_embedding)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c] 
# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(38,),name='decoder_input_layer')
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the. 
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 1024, mask_zero=True,name='decoder_embedding_layer')(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
#Attention layer which is defind in above function 
attention_layer = B_Attention_layer(state_h, state_c, encoder_outputs, decoder_embedding)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(attention_layer, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
output = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = tf.keras.models.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], output)
#compiling the model 
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy')
#model summary 
model.summary()
```

Below is my model output summary

```
Model: "model_11"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
encoder_input_layer (InputLayer [(None, 38)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_embedding_layer (Embedd (None, 38, 1024)     5796864     encoder_input_layer[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_32 (LSTM)                  [(None, 38, 1024), ( 8392704     encoder_embedding_layer[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_ExpandDims_30 (Tens [(None, 1, 1024)]    0           lstm_32[0][1]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Tanh_9 (TensorFlowO [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           lstm_32[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_layer_2 (Dense)           (None, 1, 1024)      1049600     tf_op_layer_ExpandDims_30[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_ExpandDims_31 (Tens [(None, 1, 1024)]    0           lstm_32[0][2]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_add_19 (TensorFlowO [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           tf_op_layer_Tanh_9[0][0]         
                                                                 dense_layer_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_layer_3 (Dense)           (None, 1, 1024)      1049600     tf_op_layer_ExpandDims_31[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_add_20 (TensorFlowO [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           tf_op_layer_add_19[0][0]         
                                                                 dense_layer_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_layer_1 (Dense)           (None, 38, 1024)     1049600     tf_op_layer_add_20[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Max_7 (TensorFlowOp [(None, 1, 1024)]    0           dense_layer_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_sub_7 (TensorFlowOp [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           dense_layer_1[0][0]              
                                                                 tf_op_layer_Max_7[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Exp_7 (TensorFlowOp [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           tf_op_layer_sub_7[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Sum_14 (TensorFlowO [(None, 1, 1024)]    0           tf_op_layer_Exp_7[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_truediv_7 (TensorFl [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           tf_op_layer_Exp_7[0][0]          
                                                                 tf_op_layer_Sum_14[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_mul_9 (TensorFlowOp [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           tf_op_layer_truediv_7[0][0]      
                                                                 lstm_32[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Sum_15 (TensorFlowO [(None, 1024)]       0           tf_op_layer_mul_9[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_ExpandDims_32 (Tens [(None, 1, 1024)]    0           tf_op_layer_Sum_15[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder_input_layer (InputLayer [(None, 38)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Reshape_17 (TensorF [(None, 38, 1024)]   0           tf_op_layer_ExpandDims_32[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder_embedding_layer (Embedd (None, 38, 1024)     5796864     decoder_input_layer[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_13 (Concatenate)    (None, 38, 2048)     0           tf_op_layer_Reshape_17[0][0]     
                                                                 decoder_embedding_layer[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_33 (LSTM)                  [(None, 38, 1024), ( 12587008    concatenate_13[0][0]             
                                                                 lstm_32[0][1]                    
                                                                 lstm_32[0][2]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_11 (TimeDistri (None, 38, 5661)     5802525     lstm_33[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 41,524,765
Trainable params: 41,524,765
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

when i'm fitting the model i'm facing below tensor shape error can anyone help me what exactly that

```
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_output_data, batch_size=86, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

Error :

```
Train on 4644 samples, validate on 1162 samples
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-781d7ca43c98> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', 'model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_output_data, batch_size=86, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2) ')

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2115             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2116             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2117                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2118             return result
   2119 

</usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1187         if mode=='eval':
   1188             st = clock2()
-> 1189             out = eval(code, glob, local_ns)
   1190             end = clock2()
   1191         else:

<timed eval> in <module>()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    725         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    726         workers=workers,
--> 727         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    728 
    729   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    673         validation_steps=validation_steps,
    674         validation_freq=validation_freq,
--> 675         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
    676 
    677   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    392 
    393         # Get outputs.
--> 394         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    395         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    396           batch_outs = [batch_outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3474 
   3475     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3476                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3477     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3478     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1470         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1471                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1472                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1473         if run_metadata:
   1474           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 88064 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 38912
     [[{{node Reshape_17}}]]
```

Anyone help me i'm not understanding where i did wrong

Comment: Please rewrite the subject of the question to describe what you are asking. pasting an error message isn't going to get you much help - in fact, it's not a question, is it? Next, ask something specific. Remember, S.O. isn't a "fix my code" site, it's a "help me understand this specific thing" site.

Comment: hi Benjamin R, i'm sorry my incomplete question, i'm just beginner to this site how ever thanks for your reply from next time on wards i can change my way of asking questions thanks for your suggestion can you have a look [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-HTAE0W-Tu6Yb7FaV3Gdf9G_L4ivrQb6) i'm doing this project and help me if possible thanak you :)

Answer (score 0):

the error is on line
`context_vector = tf.keras.backend.reshape(context_vector,[-1,38,1024])`
you are trying to reshape a tensor with 88064 values into a tensor with 38912 values, hence the error (38*1024 = 38912).

I'm not sure about the shape of `decoder_embedding` in

```
input_to_decoder = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([context_vector,decoder_embedding])
```

and your future plans but maybe reshaping the vector with the right values will do the trick.
`88064/1024 = 86`, so you could do:
`context_vector = tf.keras.backend.reshape(context_vector,[-1,86,1024])`

Comment: hi xenotecc, thanks for the reply as per your suggestion i changed context vector shape to 86 but getting a error at concatenation layer, and  my decoder_embedding shape is (None,38,1024) can you please visit [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-HTAE0W-Tu6Yb7FaV3Gdf9G_L4ivrQb6) for whole understanding please help me

Comment: Hey, yeah it's hard to figure out what you are trying to achieve. The only thing that comes to my mind is on the line:
`context_vector = attention_weights * encoder_outputs`
are you sure you don't want to `tf.matmul` weights with outputs?

Other than that I don't really have a clue, sorry :(

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that line with tf.mathmul  thanks for your reply :)